# List comprehension or more efficient method for this code

Tags: python, list, iteration, list-comprehension

I have the following code. For all lists inside `a` in the range 1, 4 that contain items, their length/ number of items is summed and then printed.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], None, [1.23, 4.56], ['a', 'b', 'c'], None, None] 
sum = 0

for i in a[1, 4):
    if a[i]:
        sum += len(i)

print(sum)
```

How could I simplify the middle three lines of code to make the process more efficient? Could I do this with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do it with a generator expression.  This is a construct with similar syntax to a list comprehension.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], None, [1.23, 4.56], ['a', 'b', 'c'], None, None] 
sum_ = sum(len(L) for L in a if L is not None)
print(sum_)
```

In this case you don't actually need the resulting list for anything, so you wouldn't usually use a list comprehension here.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = sum(len(i) for i in a if i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([len(element) for element in a if element])
```

This should do it~

Comment: There is no need to build a list here when all you are doing is summing the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance`to check if the subelement is a list, so if your list contains values other than `None` it will still work.

```
 sum(len(x) for x in a[1:5] if isinstance(x,list))
```

`a[1:5]` are elements `None, [1.23, 4.56], ['a', 'b', 'c'], None` or `1 - 4` :

If you want the first four elements indexes start at `0` so use `a[0:4]` which includes the start index `0` and up to but not including index `4`